# How can I deploy rolling OS upgrades & reboots with Puppet or MCollective?

Tags: puppet, rhel7, mcollective

I'm looking for the best way to perform regular rolling upgrades for my infrastructure.

Typically, this involves doing this on each host, one at a time:

```
sudo yum update -y && sudo reboot
```

But, I'm hitting limits of that being a scalable.

I want to only reboot one node at a time within each of my roles, so that, say, I don't take down all of my load balancers, or DB cluster members, at the same time.

Ideally, I'd wanna do something like:

```
for role in $(< roles_list.txt) ; do
    mco package update_all_and_reboot \
        --batch 1 --batch-sleep 90 \
        -C $role -F environment=test
done
```

But, that doesn't quite seem to exist. I'm not sure if using the "shell" agent is the best approach, either?

```
mco shell run 'yum update -y && reboot' \
    --batch 1 --batch-sleep 90
```

---

Am I just looking at the wrong sort of tool for this job, though? Is there something better for managing these sort of rolling reboots, but that I can somehow link up with my Puppet-assigned roles, so that I can be comfortable that I'm not taking down anything important all at once, but that I can still do some parallel updates & reboots?

Comment: Why the reboot (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28162/65367)? Does it needs to be puppet or are other sollutions allowed as well?

Comment: Because there are frequent Linux kernel updates lately, which do require a restart.

Comment: Ok. I have tested it and it works on my system. Could you check it on your system as well?

Answer (score 2):

**Configuration**

Deploy

```
cd /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/mcollective/application
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arnobroekhof/mcollective-plugin-power/master/application/power.rb
```

and

```
cd /usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arnobroekhof/mcollective-plugin-power/master/agent/power.ddl
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arnobroekhof/mcollective-plugin-power/master/agent/power.rb
```

on both hosts, i.e. `test-server1` and `test-server2`.

**Services**

Restart mcollective on both services:

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]# sudo service mcollective restart
```

and

```
[vagrant@test-server2 ~]# sudo service mcollective restart
```

**Commands**

Run the following commands on the mcollective server node:

The host `test-server2` is listening:

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]$ mco ping
test-server2                             time=25.32 ms
test-server1                             time=62.51 ms


---- ping statistics ----
2 replies max: 62.51 min: 25.32 avg: 43.91
```

Reboot the `test-server2`:

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]$ mco power reboot -I test-server2

 * [ ============================================================> ] 1 / 1

test-server2                             Reboot initiated

Finished processing 1 / 1 hosts in 123.94 ms
```

The `test-server2` is rebooting:

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]$ mco ping
test-server1                             time=13.87 ms


---- ping statistics ----
1 replies max: 13.87 min: 13.87 avg: 13.87
```

and it has been rebooted:

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]$ mco ping
test-server1                             time=22.88 ms
test-server2                             time=54.27 ms


---- ping statistics ----
2 replies max: 54.27 min: 22.88 avg: 38.57
```

Note that it is possible to shutdown a host as well:

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]$ mco power shutdown -I test-server2

 * [ ============================================================> ] 1 / 1

test-server2                             Shutdown initiated

Finished processing 1 / 1 hosts in 213.18 ms
```

---

[Original code](https://github.com/arnobroekhof/mcollective-plugin-power)

/usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/power.rb

> ```
> module MCollective
>   module Agent
>     class Power<RPC::Agent
>
>       action "shutdown" do
>   out = ""
>   run("/sbin/shutdown -h now", :stdout => out, :chomp => true )
>   reply[:output] = "Shutdown initiated"
>       end
>
>       action "reboot" do
>   out = ""
>   run("/sbin/shutdown -r now", :stdout => out, :chomp => true )
>   reply[:output] = "Reboot initiated"
>       end
>
>     end
>   end
> end
>
> # vi:tabstop=2:expandtab:ai:filetype=ruby
> ```

/usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/power.ddl

> ```
> metadata    :name        => "power",
>             :description => "An agent that can shutdown or reboot them system",
>             :author      => "A.Broekhof",
>             :license     => "Apache 2",
>             :version     => "2.1",
>             :url         => "http://github.com/arnobroekhof/mcollective-plugins/wiki",
>             :timeout     => 5
>
> action "reboot", :description => "Reboots the system" do
>     display :always
>
>     output :output,
>            :description => "Reboot the system",
>            :display_as => "Power"
> end
>
> action "shutdown", :description => "Shutdown the system" do
>     display :always
>
>     output :output,
>            :description => "Shutdown the system",
>            :display_as  => "Power"
> end
> ```

/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/mcollective/application/power.rb

> ```
> class MCollective::Application::Power<MCollective::Application
>   description "Linux Power broker"
>   usage "power [reboot|shutdown]"
>
>   def post_option_parser(configuration)
>     if ARGV.size == 1
>       configuration[:command] = ARGV.shift
>     end
>   end
>
>   def validate_configuration(configuration)
>     raise "Command should be one of reboot or shutdown" unless configuration[:command] =~ /^shutdown|reboot$/
>
>   end
>
>   def main
>     mc = rpcclient("power")
>
>     mc.discover :verbose => true
>     mc.send(configuration[:command]).each do |node|
>       case configuration[:command]
>       when "reboot"
>         printf("%-40s %s\n", node[:sender], node[:data][:output])
>       when "shutdown"
>         printf("%-40s %s\n", node[:sender], node[:data][:output])
>       end 
>     end
>
>     printrpcstats
>
>     mc.disconnect
>
>   end
>
> end
>
> # vi:tabstop=2:expandtab:ai
> ```

---

**Modified code**

/usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/power.ddl

```
metadata    :name        => "power",
            :description => "An agent that can shutdown or reboot them system",
            :author      => "A.Broekhof",
            :license     => "Apache 2",
            :version     => "2.1",
            :url         => "http://github.com/arnobroekhof/mcollective-plugins/wiki",
            :timeout     => 5

action "update-and-reboot", :description => "Reboots the system" do
    display :always

    output :output,
           :description => "Reboot the system",
           :display_as => "Power"
end
```

/usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/power.rb

```
module MCollective
  module Agent
    class Power<RPC::Agent    
      action "update-and-reboot" do
        out = ""
        run("yum update -y && /sbin/shutdown -r now", :stdout => out, :chomp => true )
        reply[:output] = "Reboot initiated"
      end
    end
  end
end

# vi:tabstop=2:expandtab:ai:filetype=ruby
```

**Command**

```
[vagrant@test-server1 ~]$ mco power update-and-reboot -I test-server2

 * [ ============================================================> ] 1 / 1


Finished processing 1 / 1 hosts in 1001.22 ms
```

Comment: A lot of good detail, thanks.  I was looking for a single command that could perform the update-and-reboot one at a time, for example  mco power update-and-reboot -I test-servers.   mco would then apply update-and-reboot to one server, wait for it to come back up , then apply to the second.